# Working Oracle SQL query stops working when CASE function added - gives "Right Parentheses Missing" error

Tags: sql, oracle

I have ran the below query without the CASE function, and selecting two less fields from the same table. That version runs perfect and without error. The below version tells me I am missing the Right Parentheses. I've scoured through this code and cannot, for the life of me, find what the issue is. There is nothing different between this code and the code that works except in this one I added the line with the CASE function, and I selected 2 more fields, "ID_OPER_RESPONSIBLE", "DT_ASSIGNED", and "TS_OPER_LAST_UPDTD". Please help. Thanks so much.

```
select * From

(select

"Feeder #",
"WR #",
"Building",
"Area",
"SVC Ctr",
"CREW HQ",
"Job Type",
"Wk Tp",
"Description",
"Project Code",
"Status",
"Status Desc",
"Start Date",
"Req'd Date",
"Est Dlrs $",
"Est FPL Pay $",
"Est Ctr $",
"Est Matl $",
"Est Hrs",
"As Blt CMH",
"Act Dlrs $",
"Act FPL Pay $",
"Act Ctr $",
"Act Matl $",
"Act Hrs",
"CD_RQMT",
"Req-Stat-Date",
"Ad Street Prefix",
"ID_OPER_RESPONSIBLE",
"DT_ASSIGNED",
"TS_OPER_LAST_UPDTD",
"JOB CODE"

from

(select * from (select distinct

ptw."TXT_REFERENCE_3" "Feeder #",
To_Char(ptw."CD_WR") "WR #",
padd."NM_BUILDING" "Building",
ptw."CD_DIST" "Area",
ptw."CD_AREA" "SVC Ctr",
ptw."CD_CREWHQ" "CREW HQ",
ptw."TP_JOB" "Job Type",
ptw."TP_WR" "Wk Tp",
ptw."DS_WR" "Description",
ptw."CD_PROJECT" "Project Code",
ptw."CD_STATUS" "Status",
pstat."DS_STATUS" "Status Desc",
ptw."DT_SCHED" "Start Date",
ptw."DT_REQUIRED" "Req'd Date",
SUM(ptse."AMT_ADMIN_OH"+ptse."AMT_LBR_CMPNY"+ptse."AMT_MATL_OH"+ptse."AMT_MATL" + ptse."AMT_LBR_CNTCR") "Est Dlrs $",
ptse."AMT_LBR_CMPNY" "Est FPL Pay $",
ptse."AMT_LBR_CNTCR" "Est Ctr $",
ptse."AMT_MATL" "Est Matl $",
sum(ptse."HR_LBR_CMPNY"+ ptse."HR_LBR_CNTCR") "Est Hrs",
ptsasb."HR_LBR_CMPNY" "As Blt CMH",
SUM(ptsact."AMT_ADMIN_OH" + ptsact."AMT_EQUIP_OH"+ptsact."AMT_LBR_CMPNY"+ ptsact."AMT_LBR_CNTCR" + ptsact."AMT_MATL_OH"+ptsact."AMT_MATL") "Act Dlrs $",
ptsact."AMT_LBR_CMPNY" "Act FPL Pay $",
ptsact."AMT_LBR_CNTCR" "Act Ctr $",
ptsact."AMT_MATL" "Act Matl $",
ptsact."HR_LBR_CMPNY" "Act Hrs",
pts."CD_RQMT",
pts."CD_RQMT"||'-'||pts."ST_RQMT"||'-'||pts."TS_OPER_LAST_UPDTD" As "Req-Stat-Date",
padd."AD_STREET_PFX" "Ad Street Prefix",
pts."ID_OPER_RESPONSIBLE" "ID_OPER_RESPONSIBLE",
pts."DT_ASSIGNED" "DT_ASSIGNED",
Case When pts."ST_RQMT" = 'C' Then pts."TS_OPER_LAST_UPDTD" End "TS_OPER_LAST_UPDTD",
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ptex."CD_WR" ORDER BY ptex."CD_SEQ" DESC) "RNK",
ptex."CD_JOB" "JOB CODE"

from

"PSWMS"."TWMWR" ptw

LEFT JOIN "PSWMS"."TWMMILESTONERQMT" pts ON ptw."CD_WR" = pts."CD_WR"
LEFT JOIN "PSWMS"."TWMWRSUMMARY_EST" ptse ON ptw."CD_WR" = ptse."CD_WR"
LEFT JOIN "PSWMS"."TWMWRSUMMARY_ASB" ptsasb ON ptw."CD_WR" = ptsasb."CD_WR"
LEFT JOIN "PSWMS"."TWMWRSUMMARY_ACT_EXT" ptsact ON ptw."CD_WR" = ptsact."CD_WR"
LEFT JOIN "PSWMS"."TWMSTATUS" pstat ON ptw."CD_STATUS" = pstat."CD_STATUS" AND ptw."TP_WR" = pstat."TP_WR"
LEFT JOIN "PSWMS"."TWMADDRESS" padd ON ptw."CD_ADDRESS_JOB" = padd."CD_ADDRESS"
LEFT JOIN "PSWMS"."TWMIFEXTWRDETAILS" ptex ON ptw."CD_WR" = ptex."CD_WR"

WHERE

pts."CD_RQMT" in ('211','215','399','498','699','818') AND
((ptw."CD_STATUS" NOT LIKE '%X%') OR (ptw."CD_STATUS" in ('10','20','30','40','50','60','70','80','90'))) AND
((ptw."DT_SCHED" >= TO_DATE('2012-10-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:Mi:SS')) OR (ptw."DT_SCHED" IS NULL)) AND
ptw."TP_JOB" IN ('62A','62B','62C','62H','62J','62L','85A','85A_IRHH','85A_LAT','85A_MPI','85A_POIRHH','85A_POIVIS','ADDLCONT_FT','STORMFLWUP','73E','84A','84K_EEI','84N','84B','84C','84C_ADDPF','84C_INSP','84D','84D_FDR','85D','85D_ETS','85E','85K','85S','86A','86A_POW','86C','86D','86D_RAS')

group by

ptw."CD_DIST",
ptw."CD_AREA",
ptw."CD_CREWHQ",
ptw."TP_JOB",
ptw."TP_WR",
ptw."CD_WR",
ptw."DS_WR",
ptw."CD_PROJECT",
ptw."TXT_REFERENCE_3",
ptw."CD_STATUS",
pstat."DS_STATUS",
ptw."DT_SCHED",
ptw."DT_REQUIRED",
ptse."AMT_LBR_CNTCR",
ptse."HR_LBR_CMPNY",
ptsasb."HR_LBR_CMPNY",
ptsact."AMT_LBR_CNTCR",
ptsact."HR_LBR_CMPNY",
pts."CD_RQMT",
pts."ST_RQMT",
pts."TS_OPER_LAST_UPDTD",
padd."AD_STREET_PFX",
ptse."AMT_LBR_CMPNY",
ptse."AMT_MATL",
ptsact."AMT_LBR_CMPNY",
ptsact."AMT_MATL",
padd."NM_BUILDING",
pts."ID_OPER_RESPONSIBLE",
pts."DT_ASSIGNED",
pts."TS_OPER_LAST_UPDTD"
ptex."CD_WR",
ptex."CD_SEQ",
ptex."CD_JOB") where RNK = 1))

PIVOT (max("Req-Stat-Date") "Req", max("ID_OPER_RESPONSIBLE") "Req Assigned to", max("DT_ASSIGNED") "Req Assigned Date", max("TS_OPER_LAST_UPDTD") "Req Comp Date"  for "CD_RQMT" in ('211' "211",'215' "215",'399' "399",'498' "499",'699' "699",'818' "818"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's nothing to do with the case expression. You are missing a comma after `pts."TS_OPER_LAST_UPDTD"`:

```
pts."DT_ASSIGNED",
pts."TS_OPER_LAST_UPDTD"
------------------------^
ptex."CD_WR",
ptex."CD_SEQ",
ptex."CD_JOB") where RNK = 1))

PIVOT (max("Req-Stat-Date") "Req", max("ID_OPER_RESPONSIBLE") "Req Assigned to", max("DT_ASSIGNED") "Req Assigned Date", max("TS_OPER_LAST_UPDTD") "Req Comp Date"  for "CD_RQMT" in ('211' "211",'215' "215",'399' "399",'498' "499",'699' "699",'818' "818"))
```

If you use an IDE like SQL Developer then things like that should be highlighted before you even try to run the query; and even if you don't most clients (including SQL*Plus) should report the line number the error is on. In this case it actually points to the first character of the next line, but that still gets you close enough to be able to spot it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't believe I missed that. Going forward I will use an editor. Thanks again.

Comment: This is one reason why commas go on the left.